# What is the reason of Corrupted fields problem in SPLUNK?

Tags: search, report, field, splunk, execute

I have a problem on this search below for last 25 days:

index=syslog Reason="Interface physical link is down" OR Reason="Interface physical link is up" NOT mainIfname="Vlanif*" "nw_ra_a98c_01.34_krtti"

Normally field7 values are like these ones:

Region field7 Date mainIfname Reason count
ASYA nw_ra_m02f_01.34pndkdv may 9 GigabitEthernet0/3/6 Interface physical link is up 3
ASYA nw_ra_m02f_01.34pldtwr may 9 GigabitEthernet0/3/24 Interface physical link is up 2

But recently they wee like this:

00:00:00.599 nw_ra_a98c_01.34_krtti
00:00:03.078 nw_ra_a98c_01.34_krtti

I think problem may be related to:

It started to happen after the disk free alarm. (-Cri- Swap reservation, bottleneck situation, current value: 95.00% exceeds configured threshold: 90.00%. : 07:17 17/02/20)
Especially This is not about disk, it's about swap space, the application finishes memory and then goes to swap use. There was memory increase before, but obviously it was insufficient, it is switching to swap again.
I need to understand: ''Why they use so many resources?''[image]

[image]

Problematic one:

Normal one:

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide example events, one from the normal situation, and one from the problematic situation.

It appears that someone in your environment has developed a field extraction for field7, which is incorrectly parsing the event.

Alternatively, it could the device that is sending the syslog data, may have an issue with it and it is reporting an error. Depending on the device, you may be better using a TA from splunkbase.splunk.com to extract the relevant information from the event

Comment: I've attached the xample events, one from the normal situation, and one from the problematic situation. 
 https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1IaswXnbWTORN0ES0NzL0ceDAHr4iIyS6?usp=sharing